# How to restore MYSQL database after installing a different version of WAMP?

Tags: mysql, database, version, wampserver, restore

I would like to know How to restore MYSQL database after installing a different version of Wampserver. The explanation is as below:

I deleted the wampserver folder accidentally and I lost my MYSQL database. However, I have succeeded to restore the data folder that contains the database and I have installed another version of Wampserver (Actually, the old version of MYSQL that I was using was **5.5.8** , and the MYSQL version that I am using right now is **5.6.17**) and I have tried to restore the database by copying its folder and putting it and the old ibdata1 file under the data folder of the new installation. But, unfortenately, that doesn't work.

So, my questions are:

1. Is it possible to restore MYSQL database after installing a different version of Wampserver (with a different version of MYSQL)?
2. If yes, how can I do that? What would be the solution?

Comment: Export Mysql database through phpmyadmin then install new version and import the database again

Comment: @PayerAhammed: I don't have a MYSQL database. As I said, I have just the folder. If I had the exported Mysql database, I would import it very easily. But the problem is that I have just its folder under the data folder.

Comment: stop your mysql server then copy previous data folder file to new data folder the run mysql again hope it work

Comment: @PayerAhammed: Yes, I already did that, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In the past when this has happened to me, the only option that worked was to reinstall an older version of WAMP (i.e. MySQL) to match what my databases were created in originally.
If you install the same WAMP again, copying the folder should work now.

If you can gain access to your databases at this point, then you can do a proper backup of them using phpmyadmin or mysqldump etc.

After you get a proper backup, remove the older WAMP version and install the latest version again. Now you have to restore the databases using the backup files in order to put them into the newer MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

If you backed up your database you can restore it using your backup file. If you are using a graphical interface for mysql like PHPMyAdmin there is a import button you can use to import your .sql, .csv, .zip, or what ever extension you used to backup your database.

Comment: I know, but the problem is that I don't have any kind of those file extensions. I just have the folder of my database that contains files which have the .frm extension.

Comment: Was it self hosted or did your use a hosting service somewhere? If you used a hosting service, hosting companies usually back up automatically specially if you are using a managed server. Its that is the case you can try giving them a call. If you had your db on a local machine the path is usually C:\xampp\mysql\data. You can find out for sure by looking at the location by looking at your my.ini

Comment: I'm using the local machine. Besides, I'm using Wamp not xampp. the path of the data folder is always the following: C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the folders in the data folder representing the individual databases AND THE FILES sitting in the data folder. Only copying the folders didn't work for me, but when I also copied the files, overwriting the already existing files in the data folder of the target installation of WAMP, it worked.